# Angular.js : Initializing a controller on an asynchronously loaded template?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous

I have an application where I'm loading a login modal asynchronously so it's available across the multiple platforms that make up the application. I'm loading and binding the HTML for the modal, but I can't find a way to initialize the Angular controller that is IN the modal after loading it asynchronously.  Here's the basic idea:

```
<div ng-controller="loginController" ng-init="loadModal()">
    <a ng-click="openModal()">LOG IN</a>
    <div ng-bind-html="modalHTML">
        // Once loaded, I need to initialize the AngularJS in here, fr'ex:
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="item for item in items>{{item.blerg}}</li>
        </ul>
    </div>  
</div>
```

Note, I'm not actually using ng-init, I'm loading via a service. This is a super-dumbed-down version because making JSBins takes a poopload of time.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you need to attach the loaded HTML to the controller's scope. I think the easiest way is to create a custom directive that will load the HTML, "compile" it and attach it to the modal.

Here is a simple example:

HTML

```
<div ng-controller="loginController">
    <div async-modal>
    </div>  
</div>
```

JS

```
angular.module('test', []).controller('loginController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.items = ['one', 'two', 'three'];
}).directive('asyncModal', function ($compile, $timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: false,
        link: function (scope, element) {
            // $timeout is here just to emulate async behaviour
            // this should be your loader service
            $timeout(function () {
                // lets assume that this is the loaded HTML
                var html = '<ul><li ng-repeat="item in items">{{item}}</li></ul>';
                element.append($compile(html)(scope));
            }, 1000);
        }
    };
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/e6w5p6p5/1/)

EDIT:

After some thought, you might be able to just use ng-include instead of ng-bind-html, but it does depend on how you load the HTML.